# select forms with GET METHOD

Tags: javascript, html, forms

My code below selects forms with both POST and GET methods. But I want to select forms with GET form method attribute only. How can I use selector/filters to retrieve only those form elements that set form method as GET

```
    const jsdom = require('jsdom');  
    const { JSDOM } = jsdom;  
    {  
        const {  
            document  
        } = (new JSDOM(data)).window;  
      
        var all = document.getElementsByTagName("FORM");  
      
        for (var i = 0, max = all.length; i < max; i++) {  
            var aform = document.getElementsByTagName("FORM")[i];  
      
            // log aform.outerHTML  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

[Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
let getform = document.querySelectorAll("form[method=GET]")[0].id;
console.log(getform)


let postform = document.querySelectorAll("form[method=POST]")[0].id;
console.log(postform)

let omittedform = document.querySelectorAll("form")[2];

if (!omitted.getAttribute("method")) {
  console.log(omitted.id)
}


[...document.querySelectorAll("form")].forEach(form => {
  if (!form.getAttribute("method") || form.getAttribute("method") === "GET") {
    console.log("Form with id " + form.id + "is GET")
  } else if (form.getAttribute("method") === "POST") {
    console.log("Form with id " + form.id + "is POST")
  }
});
```

```html
<form method="GET" id="get">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>

<form method="POST" id="post">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>


<form id="omitted">
  <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname">
</form>
```

And as comment suggested, if form method is omitted you would need to check if method attribute exists in HTML, if not, you can treat it as GET.

```
!omitted.getAttribute("method")
```

As we don't see your HTML, you would need use examples above to write your own logic suitable for your use case.

Or you can check it all like this:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll("form")].forEach(form => {
  if (!form.getAttribute("method") || form.getAttribute("method") === "GET" ) {
    console.log("Form with id " + form.id + "is GET")
  } else {
    console.log("Form with id " + form.id + "is POST")
  }
});
```

Comment: You forgot the case where the `method` attribute is omitted. GET is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to match more complex rules than just the element type.

A type selector can filter by forms, then attribute selectors can examine the `method` attribute.

You need to be careful because GET is the default value so you need to test for the case where there is no `method` attribute at all (with a `:not()` pseudo-class) and where it is set to `GET`

```js
const get_forms = document.querySelectorAll("form:not([method]), form[method='get']")
console.log(get_forms.length + " matching forms");
```

```html
<form method="GET"></form>

<form method="POST"></form>

<form></form>
```

Comment: This would work with only: `form:not([method=POST])`, also.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with javascript variable for which switch between form methods

```
let formMethod = undefined

let getForms = document.querySelectorAll(`form[method=${formMethod || 'GET'}]`)

formMethod = "POST"

let postForms = let forms = document.querySelectorAll(`form[method=${formMethod || 'GET'}]`)
```

you can do it also with a function

```
function findForms(method) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(`form[method=${method || 'GET'}]`)
}
let postForms = getForms("POST")
let getForms = getForms("GET")

let firstGetForm = getForms[0]
let firstGetFormId = firstGetForm.id

let secondGetForm = getForms[1]
let secondGetFormId = secondGetForm.id
```